# migrate a remote Git repository to a new Gerrit project

Tags: git, migration, gerrit

There is a server running Gerrit to which I have no ssh login permissions. I have, though, a Gerrit account with admin permissions.

How can I create a new Gerrit project and then import a remote Git repository into it? I would like all information to be migrated, e.g. branches and tags.

Here are some more information:

Gerrit server hostname : *gerrit.example.com*

Old Git repo URL : *ssh://git@git.example.com/foobar*

New Gerrit project name : *foobar*

Gerrit user account with admin permissions : *erik*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could run this shell script on your local desktop. Shell variables are set in the script to match your situation.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Replace these variable values according to your situation
gerritproject=foobar
gerritserver=gerrit.example.com
gerritadmin=erik
giturl=ssh://git@git.example.com/foobar

set -e
gitdir=`mktemp -d`
ssh -p 29418 $gerritadmin@$gerritserver gerrit create-project --name $gerritproject
cd $gitdir
git clone --mirror $giturl tmpname
cd tmpname
git remote add gerritremote ssh://$gerritadmin@$gerritserver:29418/$gerritproject
git push gerritremote refs/*:refs/*
```

Comment: I answered my own question as I found it hard to come by this information. I hope the answer is correct. Maybe someone could comment on that?

Comment: Pretty much, but don't forget to push refs/tags/*. To get all refs I'd clone with `--mirror` and push refs/*:refs/*.

Comment: @MagnusBäck I edited the answer following your suggestions. Does it look alright now?

Comment: Yes, it looks good. One possible caveat: If the original repository is a Gerrit repository (or was at some point) you'll have a refs/meta/config ref that you may or may not want to push, and it's highly likely that attempting to push it will result in a non-fast forward update.

Comment: Will the history be migrated as well?